# flask error handler is not getting called

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

I have a flask website in which I tried implementing an error handler but it does not work.
For example when I raise an `abort(400)` my error handler is not being called.

The part of my code:

```
@app.route("/terms", methods=["GET"])
def terms():
    abort(400)
    return render_template("terms.html")

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_bad_request():
    return render_template("error.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def handle_bad_request(error)
    return render_template("error.html"), 400
```

In this error (def handle_bad_request(error)) is an argument , you can add what ever you want, try adding error or e preferably.